# How to change screenshot application to Flameshot on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, screenshot

I needed to highlight some text in my screenshots and I did not know how to do it with the default screenshot app.
[Flameshot](https://flameshot.org/) is a solution. I installed it.

How can I replace the <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> shortcut-key so that it launches Flameshot?

Comment: You should cut out everything from the second sentence onward, post it as an answer and delete it from the question so that the Q&A format is mantained.

Comment: Since Ask Ubuntu is a question and answer site, you should post the answer separately as @dsSTORM said. I have removed the answer part from the question, but you can find it [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1036473/1). Please post the answer in "Your Answer" section below. It's completely fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 224):

If you need or want to replace the <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> shortcut do the following:

1. Release the <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> binding by this command

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot '[]'
   ```
2. Go to *Settings* -> *Devices* -> *Keyboard* and scroll to the end. Press **+** and you will create custom shortcut.
   [image: custom shortcuts in ubuntu 18.04]
3. Enter name: "*flameshot*", command: `/usr/bin/flameshot gui` or `/snap/bin/flameshot`.
4. Set shortcut to <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> (print).

That is it. Next time you push <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> flameshot will be launched.

---

*Source*: [Posted in the question by OP](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1036473/1) which should have been posted as an answer instead.

Comment: You need `[]` inside the `''` so it should be `'[]'`. Otherwise this should be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: If it's installed as a snap just set the command to `flameshot gui` (without the path)

Comment: Strange that Flameshot has configuration options for a myriad of keyboard shortcuts except for the most important one.

Comment: Working in my PopOS 21.04. Thanks!

Comment: And depending on how you installed Flameshot, check the path. With Snapshot this will be /snap/bin/flameshot

Comment: Worked well for me, except I was using snap, so I had to use `/snap/bin/flameshot gui`, and the way to get to the setting through Settings was a bit different than described here since I am using Ubuntu 21.10. But it wasn't too hard to find.

Comment: @niclas-lindgren Thank you!

Comment: If you're using the flatpak version the command is: 
flatpak run org.flameshot.Flameshot gui

Answer (score 47):

Install and setup flameshot via terminal
... if there is no `custom0` shortcut / binding 
configured

**Install flameshot:**

```
sudo apt install flameshot
```

**Release the <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> binding by this command:**

*Ubuntu 19.10 (Credits: @jobou's comment)*

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot '[]'
```

*Older Ubuntu versions:*

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot ''
```

**Set new custom binding:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']"
```

**Set name:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name 'flameshot'
```

**Set command:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command '/usr/bin/flameshot gui'
```

**Set binding:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding 'Print'
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.10, I had to release the `PtrScr` binding with this command `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot '[]'`

Comment: This worked on Fedora 31!

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: works on Elementary OS, Hera 5.1

Comment: works perfectly

Comment: This is the Linux answer, only commands, no clicking, works.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, the binding has moved it seems. Run: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings show-screenshot-ui '[]'`

Comment: Can you also add support for the alternative screenshot modes, `<Shift>Print` and `<Alt>Print`?

Answer (score 19):

In case you installed Flameshot via [snapcraft.io](https://snapcraft.io/) and not via standard `sudo apt install flameshot`, then the path `/usr/bin/flameshot gui` will not work, because the path is different.

1. So, first run command `type flameshot` (for Ubuntu 18.04 and higher). This will show you the path where app is installed.
2. Copy this path.
3. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> and search for keyboard shortcut.
4. Find word screenshot

   [image: see this example]
5. Edit it (in my case, I assigned <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> as I have never used this key combo)
6. Then go back, click <kbd>+</kbd> symbol and add the path you have copied to command.

   [image: and see this example]

Comment: `which` also works as well as `type`, but it won't say if it's a terminal command if it is

Answer (score 17):

This is tested on Ubuntu 20.04

1. Disable <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> or **Print** shortcut by opening the Keyboard Shortcuts Settings
2. Navigate to **Keyboard Shortcuts** on bottom left menu, then select **Print** shortcut which is to **Save a screenshot to Pictures**

   [image: keyboard shortcuts dialog]
3. Hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to disable the current keyboard shortcut so that we can use this for Flameshot later.
4. Hit **Set** to apply/confirm it.

   [image]
5. Identify Flame binary location with `which` command

   ```
   $ which flameshot
   /usr/bin/flameshot
   ```
6. Then, scroll down to the bottom and select **+** symbol to add new shortcut.

   [image]
7. Add Custom Shortcut

   - Name: Flameshot
   - Command: /usr/bin/flameshot gui
   - Shortcut: Print

   [image]

That's it

Comment: Also verified works on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @ChristianWilkie in 22.04 you can directly add the shortcut, it will ask to disable the 'old' binding.

Answer (score 4):

Or simply set any shortcut (including  <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>) to `flameshot gui`: as indicated in the other answers, only without the need for any other setting. You will be asked if you want to remap the key (in Xfce at least, but I guess it's the same in most desktops).

You might consider keeping  <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> for the default screenshot tool and use other shortcuts for flameshot, at least two I mean, because you can also capture screen **with delay**: for a 5-second delay, use `flameshot gui -d 5000`.

More [here](https://cmolinaord.github.io/using-flameshot-screenshot.html).

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the System Settings app and select **Devices**, then go to **Keyboard**.
2. Scroll down to **Screenshots**. Select *Save a screenshot to Pictures* and hit delete to disable the shortcut.
3. Then scroll all the way to the bottom and hit the plus button. Here, give it a name and type the Flameshot command you want to bind to the shortcut.
4. Then set the shortcut as Print Screen and for command type `flameshot gui`.

You’re done.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04:

1. Remove the keyboard shortcut assigned for <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>:

   **Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts** -> Click *Save a screenshot to Pictures* -> Press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to unassign.
2. Assign Flameshot to <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>:

   Press the **+** icon -> Name: Flameshot -> Command: flameshot GUI -> Set Shortcut -> Press <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> -> Click Add to save.

Answer (score 1):

Steps worked on Pop!_OS 22.04.

1. Go to Settings -> *Keyboard* -> *Keyboard Shortcuts* -> View and Customize shortcuts.
2. Search 'screenshot' and remove the 'Take a screenshot interactively'.

   [image: Configuration]
3. In the same window, search for *Custom shortcuts* -> Add (+ icon) -> Set this configuration:

Screenshot by Flameshot
`/usr/bin/flameshot` GUI
Print (or the key you want to configure)

[image]

Comment: This is a copy of an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Working in Kubuntu 20.10 :

Go to System Settings

[image: SystemSettings]

**Shortcuts > Global shortcuts**

[image: Settings_shotcut]

click **Add Application** button (you can type "flameshot" on the search box)

[image: addAplication]

click **OK**

After adding the application, you should see a tab with *Take screenshot* description.

[image: link PrtScr key to shortcut]

Click on it, and press the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> key on your keyboard to set the shortcut.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to the solution that other people wrote about already.
If you did everything correct and still nothing happens when pressing the "Print Screen" button. Double check if you haven't installed flameshot via snap. If you did then command would be a bit different:

```
/snap/bin/flameshot gui
```

To find your exact flameshot location path type in terminal

```
type flameshot
```

And you should be able to see exact path to the executable you should be using as command (just add additional gui keyword behind it).
Hope that helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

An update for those that have installed via FlatPak.  The binary command to bind to your shortcut key is:

```
/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=/app/bin/flameshot org.flameshot.Flameshot gui --delay 500
```

At least, that's what it is on Ubuntu Jammy/Mint Vera x86_64.

I found that command by examining the .desktop file @ /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications:

```
egrep ^Exec.*gui /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/org.flameshot.Flameshot.desktop
```

And taking the command after the Exec= line.