# Freeze screen before regional screenshot capture

Tags: gnome, configuration, screenshot

I'm looking to imitate ShareX's behaviour in Gnome. I want the screen to freeze before I take a regional screenshot. It would also be nice to get other features of ShareX too, however, I'm not sure if that's easily achievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KDE has an awesome screenshot tool that does exactly what I want called "Spectacle". It works (perhaps surprisingly) well on Gnome too.

To install Spectacle: `sudo apt install kde-spectacle`

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but switching from windows I missed that feature a lot. I just recently discovered flameshot which does exactly that (with additional features like making some small edits on the fly).

You can install it via: `sudo apt install flameshot`
and then invoking it on the command line via `flameshot gui`

However, that seemed annoying to me so I also created a shortcut with the print button (you need to disable the standard screenshot first though). See [Ubuntu 18 how to change screenshot application to Flameshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036473/ubuntu-18-how-to-change-screenshot-application-to-flameshot)